# error python selenium, [object Text]. It should be an element

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.lordswm.com/")
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//b[text()="Nickel"]/following-sibling::text()[1]')

print(x)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGNUC.png)

this is the error: [object Text]. It should be an element.

HTML Code

```
    <td class="wb" valign="top">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <b>Parts of an uncommon creature stack</b>: 109<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Parts of a rare creature stack</b>: 59<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Imperial amulet</b>: 42<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Imperial boots</b>: 4<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Imperial dagger</b>: 8<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Imperial ring</b>: 2<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Dark armour</b>: 1<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Dark axe</b>: 36<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Dark dagger</b>: 20<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Dark ring</b>: 20<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Dark bow</b>: 45<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Heaven cloak</b>: 1<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Heaven bow</b>: 58<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Heaven shield</b>: 5<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Fire crystal</b>: 2<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Ice crystal</b>: 2<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Meteorite shard</b>: 1<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Moonstone</b>: 3<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<b>Nickel</b>: 702<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <b>Windflower</b>: 2<br></td>
```

how I can to fix this problem I want to the number 702

```
<b>Nickel</b>
: 702
```

and  print it

Answer (score 0):

The URL in your screenshot and the one you're trying to scrape in the first code snippet are different. Try with the URL on the screenshot and see if it works.